# err_connection_refused when i try to connect to my custom wordpress installation on local, using other device (Xampp)

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I'm trying to test my website (local) on other devices, like a smartphone,... (same lan)

If i write:

```
192.168.1.***/dashboard
```

the Xampp's dashboard appears correctly.

But when i try:

```
192.168.1.***/my-wp-installation
```

the following error come out:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I also changed wordpress/site url on Wordpress and wp-config, but nothing.

This is htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp-site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the site url

Edit wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://192.168.1.123/wp-site' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://192.168.1.123/wp-site' );
```

And finally look for firewall settings.
Open TCP Port 80 in Windows Firewall
https://wiki.mcneel.com/zoo/window7firewall

Comment: I used define ('WP_HOME','http://192.168.1.123/wp-site');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://192.168.1.123/wp-site'); using my ip address. I also edit wp_options

Comment: Can you edit `wp-config.php` and add `define('RELOCATE',true);` ?

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes, windows 10

Comment: Can you access something else from your phone, like `phpmyadmin` ? Is your firewall blocking requests?

Comment: Now that you mention it, phpmyadmin don't work neither. Maybe, simply, is the firewall blocking request

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try to open the 80 port in firewall and try again.

Comment: Now, when i enter 192.168.1.123/phpmyadmin a page appears with written "Access Forbidden" and i think it's correct, but when i try 192.168.1.123/wp-site nothing: i noticed that the url change, for example, instead of 192.168.1.123/wp-site there is localhost/wp-admin

Comment: Try to remove the relocate. `define( 'RELOCATE', true );`

Comment: I removed but nothing change

Comment: Do you have other redirections in your `.hracess` file?

Comment: I don't know, i never used it. I add the code to my request.

Comment: So the main issue now is that `192.168.1.123/wp-site` redirects you to `localhost/wp-admin` and you have no custom redirect in your `.htacess` file so it must be something from wordpress.

Comment: Try to see if any of these steps help: https://bobcares.com/blog/wordpress-wp-admin-redirect-problem/

Comment: Thank you for your help and time, now i'll give a look.